# "Excellent foreign scholar" from Chinese National Science Foundation

Tags: funding, asia

I am reading a colleague's CV which lists an "Excellent Foreign Scholar" scholarship from the National Science Foundation of China.  I am not familiar with this program, nor is google particularly helpful for me as a complete non-speaker of Chinese.  Is anyone familiar with this program, and what it would entail?

Comment: Are you talking about [National Natural Science Foundation of China](http://www.nsfc.gov.cn/publish/portal1/)?

Comment: @scaaahu:  I don't know, just reading off the CV, but I would imagine that that's the one.

Comment: These types of things are very hard to verify. If he had a Chinese-language version CV, then you might get further.

Answer (score 4):

*Preamble: I am one of a few Chinese active participants on this site. There have been some questions about Chinese academics here. I always tried to not to answer them. For example, there was a question about the role of correspondence author in Chinese academia(the OP even offered a bounty for it). I did not answer them for two reasons: I am not an insider and I do not wish to give out information I am not absolutely certain about. However, I feel that I need to give some answer for this question because I just see some un-useful answer. Hopefully some Chinese scholars will answer them after they see this one.*

According to this [document](http://www.access4.eu/_media/NSFC_4_new.pdf), "The Joint Research Fund for Overseas Chinese Scholars and Scholars in Hong Kong and Macao is established by Natural Science Foundation of China (NSFC) to encourage **excellent** overseas Chinese scholars (including those with **foreign** nationalities) under the age of 50 to conduct high-level joint research with researchers and organizations in mainland China."

I suspect your colleague received this fund. Please note that the qualification is oversea Chinese scholar. "Foreign" here means he could be born in oversea but at least one of his parents is a Chinese.

Answer (score -2):

Go to google for china and you can ask that it translate the page. You will find several articles related to the "Excellent Foreign Scholar" scholarship from the National Science Foundation of China.

Comment: "Google it" is generally not a helpful answer. Perhaps you could link to some of these articles and summarize their content here.

Comment: As far as I know, there is **no** "National Science Foundation of China". However, "National **Natural** Science Foundation of China" is a Chinese government organization.